# Can Swifter be used for a tvOS app?

Tags: swift, twitter, tvos

I am trying to access twitter data for a social media app for tvOS as a school project. I have come across Swifter (https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter) and noted that it does only say it supports iOS and Mac. I was wondering if there is any workaround to use this in tvOS since they are all written in the same language?

(as you can tell I'm pretty new to this)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the issues in the repo it appears somebody is already working on adding tvOS support so hopefully that might be ready in time for you.

In fact, somebody may have already done it: https://github.com/kindoblue/Swifter